# How can you bundle Angular 2 using System JS Builder?

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification, systemjs

I'm currently using System JS with System JS Builder to bundle up my application, its assets, and the libraries that it references. My problem is that I can bundle libraries that are referenced explicitly in the index.html, e.g:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

However, I can't figure out how I can bundle Angular 2 itself, or at least the modules required from Angular 2, as they aren't actually referenced in the HTML. How can this be done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using systemjs-builder you can bundle Angular 2 with your app code and bundle your other libraries separately.

I bundled any library I would reference directly in HTML into a vendors.min.js, and any library referenced through my system.config.js plus app code into an app.min.js. In this [example](https://tour-of-heroes-typescript.herokuapp.com/) you can see that all the dependencies in Tour of Heroes are loaded into the page in <10 network requests ([source code](https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L63)).

```js
// Bundle dependencies into vendors file
gulp.task('bundle:libs', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js',
        'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.min.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'system.config.js',
      ])
        .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/lib/js'));
});

// Compile TypeScript to JS
gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
  return gulp
    .src([
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "typings/*.d.ts"
    ])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc({
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "public/dist/js",
        "target": "ES5"
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
});

// Generate systemjs-based builds
gulp.task('bundle:js', function() {
  var builder = new sysBuilder('public', './system.config.js');
  return builder.buildStatic('app', 'public/dist/js/app.min.js');
});

// Minify JS bundle
gulp.task('minify:js', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('public/dist/js/app.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['compile:ts', 'bundle:js', 'minify:js']);
```

Comment: Interesting, could you point me to the github repo of this project?

Comment: Why use uglify and not use systemjs minify option passed to `buildStatic` ?

Comment: I cloned this repo and it fails to compile.

Comment: @tsuz The master branch is currently deployed to Heroku and works as is, but if you are running on windows there are known issues.

Comment: @Steely I just cloned the repo and tried to build it but it threw compiling errors. I'm on MacOSX

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) (my preference because it does tree-shaking).

The Angular team appears to be putting together some great tooling around **Rollup** in time for the full release.  The *day 2 keynote* of ng-conf this year discussed and demonstrated the **offline compiler**.  [Start watching this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSssb9AmiJU&index=2&list=PLvhIQi22MDhMkLVbSescCLC3ceImDYftl) at 25:30.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the reply. Isn't this what SystemJS Bundler should be doing though? If I were to use Webpack then I wouldn't need to be using SystemJS Bundler, from my understanding.

Comment: Yes, different tools for generally the same job. Neither systemjs builder nor webpack do a very good job in including es6 modules -and- keeping the payload small. Rollup is the exciting one IMO, with the treeshaking. 

I was thinking that I would need to create custom scripts to use rollup with my ng2 projects.  I was quite excited when Rob Wormald did that ng-conf demo!  Angular 2 will have built-in support.

Comment: Here's a [good article](https://medium.com/@richavyas/aha-moments-from-ngconf-2016-part-1-angular-2-0-compile-cycle-6f462f68632e#.pvbfyi19r) about packaging angular 2 apps.

Comment: I think systemjs-builder includes tree shaking by default now, if you look at the package.json, rollup is a dependency